# Formatting of collections in watch window [visual studio code]

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

A long time ago I used Visual Studio and I remember that the watch window during debugging was much smarter in showing collections than in Visual Studio Code (which I am using now). For example, when I make a simple `List`of `Strings` and I inspect this in the watch window in VSCode I get the following

[image]

Whereas in Visual Studio the quick watch feature was much more useful:

[image]

In general, I am mostly interested in the values in the collection, which I have to dig down fourlevels of hierarchy in vscode and is quite obfuscated. Does anyone know of an extension or a way to get a more usable watch window for collections?

Comment: I googled `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection` and got `.NET`. I have no idea about the language though. Feel free to correct whatever I broke.

Answer (score 3):

This won't universally reformat the debug watch window for list,  but it may help you.
You can add attributes to your classes which will modify the display of a classes member for instance [DebuggerDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes)

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {count}")]  
class MyHashtable  
{  
    public int count = 4;  
}
```

This maybe useful, Another one that will come in handy is the [DebuggerBrowsable](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebuggerBrowsable.aspx) this will automatically hide the root and display it's children

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
```

These attributes will help control debugging on custom classes

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no extension which could reformat the debug watch view content.

- The [`OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode`](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20watch%20debug) plugin has no issue directly related to this.
- A tool like [DotNetTools](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools) is not directly [pluggable into VSCode](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/issues/414).